# Map Control for non-Bing map

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I want to put an OpenStreetMap map into my Windows Phone 7.5 application. I'd like to use Map control from

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"
```

I've created custom `TileSource`:

```
public class OSMTileSource : TileSource
{
    private const string OSMUriFormat = "http://{0}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{1}/{2}/{3}.png";

    public OSMTileSource()
    {
        this.UriFormat = OSMUriFormat;
    }

    private readonly static string[] TilePathPrefixes = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };

    public override Uri GetUri(int x, int y, int zoomLevel)
    {
        if (zoomLevel > 0)
        {
            var url = string.Format(UriFormat, TilePathPrefixes[y % 3], zoomLevel, x, y);
            return new Uri(url);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, control asks me for Bing auth key (**despite I'm not using BING maps!**). I don't want to create Bing Developer Account, I don't need to as far as I don't want to use Bing maps.
Is any work around for that control? Or is there any replacement that allows to use OSM?

Comment: Just create an account and get the key, why would you not do this?! every other dev that uses an alternate tile source does.

Comment: Yeah, but what about license? Commercial license (I'd like to use map in commercial app) has some limitations.

Comment: If you have concerns about licensing, then it's best to contact Bing directly about it. The only other map control I know is the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Windows Phone](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/windows-phone-sdk/)

Answer (score 0):

The authentication is for the use of the map control and the map data. Replacing the Bing Maps data with Open Street Maps is against the terms of use. Take a look at point 3.2p here: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html This is why you can't use the map control without authentication.

As for commercial licensing. If this is a public facing app Bing Maps offers very generous free terms of use for Windows Phone apps which allow you to generate 50,000 transactions in a 24 hour period. This is more than most applications need. If this is an internal business application then you can use 125,000 transactions a year for free. If your app exceeds the limits of the free terms of use then you would need to pay for a Bing Maps license.